# Javascript how to pass a boolean function by name

Tags: javascript

I want to pass either and or an or or not equal function as a parameter to another function.

Is there a way to acheive something similar to follows without using string comparison instead using a function call:

```
function(x, y, z){
    if(z == "and"){
        return x && y;
    }
    if(z == "or"){
        return x || y;
    }
}
```

What I want is:

```
function(x, y, func){
    func(x,y); //func can be passed as either and or or or other logical op.
}
```

Is there a shorthand for && or || function? Something similar to operator.and or operator.or?

Comment: Functions are first class citizens, so you can pass them as arguments. Your second code works.

Comment: Right, but is there a shorthand for && or || function? Something similar to operator.and or operator.or?

Comment: I am not fan of `eval` but how about `eval`ing the function behavior? could this be a good case to use `eval` for?

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash There is no need of using `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are first class citizens, so you can pass them as arguments.

I think there are no native AND and OR functions, so you must define them manually.

ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions) allow you to define them in a very short way:

```js
var f = (x, y, func) => func(x,y);
f(foo, bar, (a,b) => a && b); // foo && bar
f(foo, bar, (a,b) => a || b); // foo || bar
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you can pass any function as an argument, so something like this will work:

```
function and(x, y) {
  return x && y;
}

function or(x, y) {
  return x || y;
}

function operate(x, y, operation) {
  return operation(x, y);
}

operate(true, false, and); // => false
operate(true, false, or); // => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function as argument in JavaScript. In your scenario, you can do something like:

**Given**:

```
function doLogic(x, y, func){
    return func(x,y); // If you want the calculation result, return it too
}
```

**Usage:**

```
doLogic(false,false,function(a,b){ return a&&b }); // <-- false
doLogic(false,true,function(a,b){ return a&&b }); // <-- false
doLogic(false,true,function(a,b){ return a||b }); // <-- true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try callback functions

```
function cb_and(x, y) {
    return x && y;
}

function cb_or(x, y) {
    return x || y;
}

function do(x, y, cb) {
    cb(x, y);
}
```

Not sure if this is what you want; but this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this idea is abstracted a bit into a "predicate function". Essentially, if your function needs some kind of boolean result based upon an argument (or multiple arguments), you can accept a predicate function from the caller which can do whatever it needs to compute the value.

```
function myMysteriousFunction(x, y, predicate) {
    if (predicate(x, y)) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

JavaScript doesn't have any built in *first-class* references to its operators, but there's nothing stopping you from defining it in a common place, if you need to reuse it:

```
var operators = {
    and: function(x, y) { return x && y; },
    or: function(x, y) { return x || y; },
    equal: function(x) { return x == y; },
    // etc.
};
```